# Vinculação de dados php

Tags: php

como posso fazer pra puxar os dois dados de uma tabela usuario de uma de reserva exemplo queria puxar os dados do usuario "nome, sobrenome, cpf" ao eu reservar ele registrar todos esses dados mais a reserva o valor e a quantidade[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao Sopt. Primeiro poste a modelagem de sua tabela. Depois edite sua pergunta e seja mais claro quanto a sua dúvida.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta de forma que fique mais objetiva. Recomendo ler isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql